# Implementing Browser in Unreal Engine 4.10

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal

I am looking to add some oauth to a game I am working on. I can get the user auth to work in the browser that comes with UE4, however there is not any capability to detect changes to the currently loaded URL so I can grab the token after the user loggs in. So I'm trying to create one. I created a new C++ class that extends UWebBrowser, added this line to the Build.css file

```
PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] {"Http", "UMG"});
```

And I have this in my browser .h file so it will be available to use in blueprints

```
virtual const FText GetPaletteCategory() { return FText::FromString("Oauth Browser");
```

Now I just need to be notified of when the URL changes so I can grab to auth token but I can't seem to find a way to implement for that. I have read that it can be done though. Can anyone shed more light on this subject for me? I'd appreciate it.